# How to write a general function to find those elements of array whose sum is zero?

Tags: python

I have created a program which that takes as input an array of positive and negative numbers (0 excluded) and return those items from the array whose sum is 0. If no such items exist return, then return “No Elements found”. Here I have written separate functions for twoSum, threeSUM, fourSum... but I want to have general function which will check for nSum (n is the number of elements of array)
e.g. In this list [-4, -3, -2, -1, 10], it should return -4, -3, -2, -1 and 10 there are 5 elements whose sum is 0. I am sharing my code.

```
def twoSum(arr,n,x,lp,rp):
    while lp<rp:
        if arr[lp] + arr[rp] == x:
            return True,arr[lp],arr[rp]
        elif arr[lp] + arr[rp] < x:
            lp+=1
        else:
            rp-=1
    return False,0,0

def threeSum(arr,n,x,firstIndex):
    for i in range(firstIndex,n-2):
        check,a,b = twoSum(arr,n,x-arr[i],i+1,n-1)
        if check:
            return True,arr[i],a,b
    return False,0,0,0
            
def finding_numbers(arr, n):
    if arr[0]<0:
        check,a,b = twoSum(arr,n,0,0,n-1)
        if check:
            return a,b
        
        check,a,b,c = threeSum(arr,n,0,0)
        if check:
            return a,b,c
          
        for i in range(n-3):
            check,a,b,c = threeSum(arr,n,-arr[i],i+1)
            if check:
                return arr[i],a,b,c
    return 'No Elements found'

finding_numbers(array, n)
```

Comment: This is not "C++" nor "C" so that's why those tags where removed.

Comment: Did you have a look at numpy? I think you question can benefit from expressing exactly what you want to accomplish, without immediately talking about issues you encounter for a specific implementation route that you have chosen. What is your objective, `finding_numbers()` suggests you like to find a number in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the help of the [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from itertools:

#### Code:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combinations_that_sum_zero(arr):
    return [list(comb) for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1) for comb in combinations(arr, i) if sum(comb) == 0]

arr = [1, 2, 3, -3, 4, 5, -6]
print(combinations_that_sum_zero(arr))
```

#### Output:

```
[[3, -3], [1, 2, -3], [1, 5, -6], [2, 4, -6], [1, 2, 3, -6], [-3, 4, 5, -6], [1, 3, -3, 5, -6], [2, 3, -3, 4, -6]]
```